# Android in app billing. Is there any ability to transfer money back to user?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment

I want to make inner virtual coins which the user can sell and receive money back.
Is there any ability to implement such thing?

May be it is possible to make using PayPal?

Comment: Issue a refund from the developer console.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically from app